# php intellisense not working with custom file associations

Tags: php, delphi, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I faced a weird scenario and I seek your help. I made a custom file association

```
"files.associations": {
"*.dws": "PHP"
}
```

so my **".dws"** files are mapped as PHP. but my vscode extensions such as **PHP IntelliSense** is not working in dws file but working fine with PHP file. I researched but not able to find a solution to this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Note** that casing matters for exact identifier matching Uppercase `Markdown` cannot be equal to the lowercase `markdown`

So you have to use this:

```
"files.associations": { 
  "*.dws": "php"                     <--- Do not use Uppercase PHP 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Fareed for the info but doesn't clear my doubt. My major goal here to work PHP extension same in same way in dws file as it is working in PHP file